# onEnabled/onDisabled methods with "setComponentEnabledSettings" understanding

Tags: android, android-widget

I was studying a piece of source code from the original PowerControl Widget (`SettingsAppWidgetProvider`) and I've found the following methods:

```
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
                                        ".widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"),
                                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        Class clazz = com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider.class;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
                                        ".widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"),
                                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

Can someone explain me what they do exactly??

edit: I'm sorry my question was bad formulated..I know when they are called but I can't understand what the `setComponentEnabledSetting` pair do :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android SDK docs explain both: [`onDisabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onDisabled%28android.content.Context%29) and [`onEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onEnabled%28android.content.Context%29).

In a nutshell, `onEnabled` is called when the first instance of the widget is created, and `onDisabled` is called when the last instance of the widget is deleted/removed.

Edit: in reference to the `setComponentEnabledSetting` calls, I believe they simply used to indicate that no widgets are active and therefore any related backend processing can be halted.

Comment: I'm sorry my question was bad formulated..I know when they are called but I can't understand what the inside setComponentEnabledSetting pair do :D